# Firebase React Native: are write permissions on sensible documents secure?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a security related question that I couldn't find much information on the internet.

Suppose I have an "orders" collection, in which each document is an Order, and suppose an Order is considered paid when the attribute "paid" is true. Now, when the user makes an order, the app creates an order document (with paid=false by default) uploads it to the firebase collection. For this, the orders collection should have write permissions enabled, at least for authenticated users.

Now the question is (me coming from a web environment, but never used firebase), can a user manipulate or tamper the app, client side, in order to make the order have "paid=true" and then have it uploaded to firebase? Is this risk real?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider that any code that runs on a user's device (web, mobile, or whatever) is compromised and could be doing whatever an attacker wants.  This means that any code to read and write the database could be doing something other than what you expect.  Your security rules need to defend against that.  If what you're trying to do is not possible with security rules, you will need to force the users through a backend you control to sanitize and validate any inputs to your system.

Comment: Alright, I had a feeling this was the case, but as I don't know much about Firebase SDK if it had some sort of way to prevent that, and as I couldn't find much info about this, I was unsure. Okay, I will have to make use of cloud functions for all sensible operations then.